# Lisp tokenizer from character stream in Python

Tags: python, parsing, lisp, tokenize

I enjoyed reading about Peter Norvig's cheap and cheerful Lisp interpreter here:

http://norvig.com/lispy.html

In his code, he uses this very simple function to tokenize the input Lisp code:

```
def tokenize(chars):
    "Convert a string of characters into a list of tokens."
    return chars.replace('(', ' ( ').replace(')', ' ) ').split()
```

I'd like to rewrite this as a generator which can operate on a stream, something like this:

```
def tokenize(stream):
    "Generate a stream of tokens from a stream of characters."
    # Do something here
    yield token  # This would be wrapped in a loop
```

I sketched out a state machine and started implementing it, but it quickly became more complex than expected. Is there a simpler approach which I'm missing?

Comment: Read one character: if its an opening paren, recursively read tokens into a list until you get the first closing paren; otherwise, read other kind of inputs (numbers, strings).

Comment: Thanks coredump .. your suggestion is implemented in Norvig's code, but that sounds like the parsing stage. All I want to do at this point is emit tokens, either '(', ')', or any other whitespace terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

I tried again and came up with this. It's not well tested yet, but seems to work so far.

```
def tokenise(char_stream):
  c = char_stream.read(1)
  accumulated = []

  while c:
    c_isbracket = c in '()'
    if !c.isspace() and !c_isbracket:
      accumulated.append(c)
    else:
      if accumulated:
        token_str = ''.join(accumulated)
        accumulated = []
        yield token_str
      if c_isbracket:
        yield c

    c = char_stream.read(1)
```